# Tkinter canvas: Get mouse movement without actually moving the cursor (think Photoshop resize brush)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an image annotation tool using Tkinter. A rectangular bounding box is following the cursor and is placed on the image by clicking. Now I need to be able to resize the bounding box and I'd like to do it in a similar fashion as it's done in Photoshop, holding down a button and depending on where the mouse is moved, the brush changes in size. Is that possible in Tkinter?

I've come up with this, where I wanted to add the pointer distance traveled in each direction to the rectangles size:

```py
self.canvas.bind('<Alt_L>', self.resize)
self.previousx = 0
self.previousy = 0

def resize(self, event):
    x = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)  # get coordinates of the event on the canvas
    y = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    self.rect_size[0] += (self.previousx - x) # width
    self.rect_size[1] += (self.previousy - y) # height
    self.motion(event)
    self.previousx = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    self.previousy = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
```

It kind of works too but

1. the previous coordinates need to be initialized with a different key first which is very annoying and
2. when the cursor - and with it the rectangle too - changes position it is very hard to tell if the rectangle is already the proper size.

How can I keep the cursor at the same spot and still get the mouse movements?

**Edit:**

Bryan in the comments was right, you can't move the mouse without also moving the on-screen cursor, which is true at least for my purposes. The solution was very simple, while resizing the bounding box I stopped updating it's position, so while the mouse was still moving, the rectangle did not.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: You can't move the mouse without also moving the on-screen cursor. They are intrinsically linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bryan in the comments was right, you can't move the mouse without also moving the on-screen cursor, which is true at least for my purposes. The solution was very simple, while resizing the bounding box I stopped updating it's position, so while the mouse was still moving, the rectangle did not.